Do third-party apps have full access to Files on iOS?
On iOS, when you want to use a photo in your photo library on a certain app, you will be prompted (at least for the first time) to select which photos you would like the app to be able to access, and then choose from the photos that you have granted the app access to. However, when you try to upload a file from On My iPhone or iCloud Drive, you do not need to go through the extra step. The file manager comes up, you click the file you want, and that’s it. No granting of permissions explicitly asked.
Does that mean that apps can access any file that can be found in the Files app? Or is the extra step in Photos not required precisely because apps can never access files that we do not choose?

iOS apps are sandboxed, they can only access their own files (the files which are stored within the sandbox).
What PDF Viewer uses (and any other app interacting with Files, including apps like Pages and Numbers), is the Document Browser functionality provided by the OS. The Document Browser runs outside of the control of the app, all the app gets back at the end is access to the file you selected (or created).
PS: Apple‘s documentation on this has the details.
